# How do I make telephone links that Microsoft Lync can open?

Tags: lync-2013

I am trying to make a `.html` page that can work with Microsoft Lync. But, i can't seem to get it to work.

I would appreciate detailed description.

Example:

- `<a href="tel:123456789">Open a Lync Window the boss man.</a>`
- `<a href="tel:txt:boss@boss.com">chat with the boss man.</a>`
- `<a href="tel:call:boss@boss.com">call with the boss man.</a>`

Comment: I remember disabling the Lync add-on in IE that recognized phone numbers, email addresses on web pages.  Perhaps check to see if that feature is enabled for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure the "Lync click to call" add-on is enabled in your browser.  With that the add-on enabled the following will work:-

```
 - <a href="tel:123456789">Open a Lync Window the boss man.</a>
 - <a href="sip:boss@boss.com">IM Chat with boss man.</a>
```

Notice the "sip:" prefix in the second example.